# How to display a check mark or tick mark using unicode characters in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

[image]i want to display a check mark or tick mark using ascii or unicode characters set.
 i have the following code

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
 Value: Integer;
begin
Value:=10004
Msgbox('The character is'+chr(Value),mbinformation,mb_ok);
end;
```

But that check mark or tick mark is not displayed..

please help me on this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`CHECK MARK`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm) character has the 0x2713 hexadecimal ordinal value for UTF-16 encoding in Unicode table, so you can write what you want this way:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  C: Char;
begin
  C := #$2713;
  Msgbox('The character is: ' + C, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Hi TLama, The above code not showing the check mark . i am getting exclamation mark

Comment: i am using inno 5.5.4 version and not sure whether it has been set to unicode

Comment: It cannot be *set to Unicode*. There are two versions of Inno Setup. ANSI and Unicode. You can determine the version you have in title bar of the script editor. There you'll see either *Inno Setup Compiler 5.5.4 (a)* if you have the ANSI one or *Inno Setup Compiler 5.5.4 (u)* if you have the Unicode one. ANSI version cannot work with Unicode chars, so if you have ANSI version you'll need to download and install the Unicode one. It's on the [`download page`](http://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php) labeled as `isetup-5.5.4-unicode.exe`.

Comment: Hi TLama, i have Inno Setup Compiler 5.5.4 (a) installed in my system . Then it is ANSI format and how to display that check mark

Comment: The ANSI version doesn't support Unicode chars. So you will never see it in your Inno Setup. If you want to ever see any Unicode char you will have to install the Unicode version.

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Miral, the question was modified. What is shown on the screenshot is the result of my code from this post running in ANSI Inno Setup.